# Compare two strings according to defined values in a query

Tags: mysql

I have to compare two string fields containing letters but not alphabetically.

I want to compare them according to this order :

```
"J" "L" "M" "N" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "H" "V" "W" "Y" "Z"
```

So if I compare H with T, H will be greater than T (unlike alphabetically)

And if I test if a value is greater than 'H' (> 'H') I will get all the entries containing the values ("V" "W" "Y" "Z") (again, unlike alphabetical order)

How can I achieve this in one SQL query?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  FIELD(col, 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y', 'Z') >
  FIELD('H', 'J', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y', 'Z')
         ^ your value
```

Or also:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  LOCATE(col, 'JLMNPQRSTHVWYZ')>
  LOCATE('H', 'JLMNPQRSTHVWYZ')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7fab/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY yourletterfield='J' DESC, yourletterfield='L' DESC, yourletterfield='M' DESC, ...
```

The equality operator will evaluate to "1" when it's true, "0" when false, so this should give you the desired order.

There's actually a [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function that will make this a bit less verbose. See [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) for details.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY FIELD(yourletterfield, 'J', 'L', 'M', ...)
```

Comment: Will this method give the right results if used with comparison? Or does it only order with the given values? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: What do you mean by "used with comparison"? This will return your results in the given order. It has no bearing on the `>` and `<` operators.

Comment: I was not trying to order but to compare according to an order. Your effort is very much appreciated. Thanks.